# Android : Get zoomed location without moving and draw a circle around it. (Not working)

Tags: android, gps, location, android-maps-v2

I am working on an Android application in which I would like to display the users immediate location, not when the location has changed. Also, I would like to mark the area with a circle as soon as location is determined by zooming in. Unfortunately, the code is only working when location is changed. I tried the code sitting on my desk, and it doesn't work, but when I am walking around, it did work. What should I do.

Here is the code :

```
public class MapsActivityFragment extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    private MapAreaManager circleManager;
    static GoogleMap googleMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;
    double longitude, latitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_maps_activitiy);

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = fm.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
            onLocationChanged(location);

        }

    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
            if (googleMap != null) {
                setupMap();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 0, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        googleMap.clear();// clean the map
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void setupMap() {
        circleManager = new MapAreaManager(googleMap,

                4, Color.RED, Color.HSVToColor(70, new float[] {1, 1, 200}), //styling

                R.drawable.move, R.drawable.resize, //custom drawables for move and resize icons

                0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //sets anchor point of move / resize drawable in the middle

                new MapAreaMeasure(100, MapAreaMeasure.Unit.pixels), //circles will start with 100 pixels (independent of zoom level)

                new MapAreaManager.CircleManagerListener() { //listener for all circle events

                    @Override
                    public void onResizeCircleEnd(MapAreaWrapper draggableCircle) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityFragment.this, "do something on drag end circle: " + draggableCircle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCreateCircle(MapAreaWrapper draggableCircle) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityFragment.this, "do something on crate circle: " + draggableCircle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMoveCircleEnd(MapAreaWrapper draggableCircle) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityFragment.this, "do something on moved circle: " + draggableCircle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMoveCircleStart(MapAreaWrapper draggableCircle) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityFragment.this, "do something on move circle start: " + draggableCircle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResizeCircleStart(MapAreaWrapper draggableCircle) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityFragment.this, "do something on resize circle start: " + draggableCircle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMinRadius(MapAreaWrapper draggableCircle) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityFragment.this, "do something on min radius: " + draggableCircle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMaxRadius(MapAreaWrapper draggableCircle) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityFragment.this, "do something on max radius: " + draggableCircle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 6));
    }

}
```

I have changed a bit of circle marking and using [this](https://github.com/i-schuetz/map_areas) library for the same. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is the best way to get last location: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/2938203

Comment: @Dichoben : That gives the location, which I already have. How does that help me? I want to show the area zoomed in and mark it using the location which I already have with me.

Answer (score 0):

If your device never had a decent GPS fix, the `getLastKnownLocation(...)`method probably returns null.  When I acquired my first GPS fix outside, I had my app working fine inside my room and also after restarting my app.